# Codeigniter 3.0.6 Login not working

Tags: sql, authentication, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am going to build a very simple register/login system for the purpose of testing, but I've never got logged in by the registered email and password.

Here is my Login_controller:

```
<?php

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($msg = NULL) {
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}

public function process() {
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result) {
        // If not valid user, then show them login page again
        $msg = 'Invalid email and/or password';
        $this->index($msg);
    }
    else {
        // If valid user, go to homepage
        redirect('home_view'); 
    }        
}
}
```

My Login_model:

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function validate() {
    // Get user input
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // Prepare the query
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // Check result
    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
        // If there is a user then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->username,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    else {
    // If the previous process did not validate then return false
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And my Login_view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Login Zokzak </h1>

    <?php
        echo form_open('Login_controller/process');
    ?>

    Email: <input type="email" name="email"/> <br> <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

    <?php
        if(!is_null($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make difference between loading view and redirecting page. If `home_view` is `APPPATH.'views'` directory's file `redirect('home_view');` won't work. [Redirect function](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) accepts REQUEST_URI string - in example `redirect('controller_name/method_name/param1/param2')`. View file is loaded by CI loader. For creating message you need to use [flash session](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) that will be available on next request.

```
if(! $result) {
    // If not valid user, then show them login page again
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Invalid email and/or password');
    redirect('login_controller');//index method is loaded by default
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Successfully Logged In.');
    redirect('top_secret_controller/admin_dashboard_method');
}
```

In `Top_secret_controller.php`:

```
class Top_secret_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    private $logged_in = FALSE;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logged_in = ( isset($_SESSION['validated']) && $_SESSION['validated'] === 1 ) ? TRUE : $this->logged_in;//in your model use integer for validated value instead TRUE to [avoid confusing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html) with converting to integer since in DB it will be writen as 1

        $this->logged_in || redirected('login');//if not logged in redirect to login page
    }

    public admin_dashboard_method()
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Quick YT search will give you bunch of videos (like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4TOYyVtP3M)) about login system so you could compare good practices with your own. Personally, I am using [Ion Auth system](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) not wanting inventing the wheel (unless I need one that is more rounder :P ).